# How can i recover ext4 free space after deleting it accidentally?

Tags: boot, kernel, data-recovery, error-handling, bleachbit

Hello (sorry if this might seem stupid but I need help)..

(Using a Dell Latitude 3510, Core i5, 512GB SSD, 8GB RAM and running ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)

I accidentally deleted the free disk space while using the ***bleachbit app***.. and lost all the space left on the device (about 452GB).. since recovery was unlikely i thought that if i recovered my system using ***Timeshift*** to the day i had it backed up,i'd theoretically recover my system.. but once the system booted i got this message:

**---[ kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100 ] ---**

then i tried restarting the system to access the grub boot sequence to revert back to factory reset (ubuntu 18.04) but i got these messages instead:

```
[33.929386] sd-umoun [4689]: Failed to  unmount /oldroot: Device or resource busy
[33.930574] sd-umoun [4690]: Failed to  unmount /oldroot/dev/pts:Device or resource busy 
[33.931843] sd-umoun [4691]: Failed to  unmount /oldroot/dev:Device or resource busy 
[33.940166] shutdown[1]: failed to finalize file system, ignoring
[33.963983] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:if.3: error: no reply expected, received 0x0
[37.061982] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:if.3: error: DMA trigger stop failed 
[37.062051] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:if.3: error: load fw failed ret: -110
[37.062166] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:if.3: error: status = 0x00000000 panic = 0x00000000
[37.062246] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:if.3: error: failed to reset DSP
[37.062299] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:if.3: error: failed to boot DSP firmware after resume -110
[37.530375] reboot: Power down
```

and I cant seem to do anything from there; force shutting down and then restarting brings me back to the same issue

(BTW zero knowledge in the computer science field.. newbie linux user.. new laptop.. no virtual machine.. no data i care to retrieve other than the lost space on ext4)

Comment: Sounds weird, not sure what happend. Since you don't care about data, why don't you simply do a fresh install, seems to be the most easy approach.

Comment: This is one reason that we don't recommend the use of Bleachbit. Another reason is that leaving cruft behind for Bleachbot to remove is generally considered a bug...and most of those bugs were fixed many years ago. Your Ubuntu system does not require any third-party maintenance tools.